# how to expand only to the second level of the treeview

Tags: delphi, treeview, delphi-xe6

Ex.:

```
    - link 1
    -- link 1.1
    --- link 1.1.1(only)
    ---- link 1.1.1.1 (not expand)
    -- link 1.2
    --- link 1.2.1 (only)
    ---- link 1.2.1.1 (not expand)
```

I can expand only link 1.1, link 1.2... how?

Comment: You should always add the generic `delphi` tag to your delphi related questions to have the correct syntax highlighter and more attention on your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no build-in functionality for expanding multiple items or items on a specific level, so there is no other way then traversing through the items. Call the [`Expand`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNode.Expand) method on all second level items. As well on all first level items, otherwise the second level items will not be shown. Its `Recurse` parameter should be `False` in order not to expand a possibly third or deeper level.

There are two ways to traverse through a TreeView's items: by Item index and by Node. Normally, operations on a TreeView's items are preferably done by Node, because the `Items` property's getter traverses through **all Items** to find a single Item with a specific index. However, `TTreeNodes` caches the last retrieved item, thus by incrementing the loop Index with 1, harm will be minimized.

The easy solution then becomes:

```
procedure ExpandTreeNodes(Nodes: TTreeNodes; Level: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Nodes.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for I := 0 to Nodes.Count - 1 do
      if Nodes[I].Level < Level then
        Nodes[I].Expand(False);
  finally
    Nodes.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ExpandTreeNodes(TreeView1.Items, 2);
end;
```

Note that the `Items` property's getter is still called twice. Despite the caching mechanism, I think this still should be avoided:

```
procedure ExpandTreeNodes(Nodes: TTreeNodes; Level: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
  Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  Nodes.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for I := 0 to Nodes.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Node := Nodes[I];
      if Node.Level < Level then
        Node.Expand(False);
    end;
  finally
    Nodes.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

But then you might as well use:

```
procedure ExpandTreeNodes(Nodes: TTreeNodes; Level: Integer);
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  Nodes.BeginUpdate;
  try
    Node := Nodes.GetFirstNode;
    while Node <> nil do
    begin
      if Node.Level < Level then
        Node.Expand(False);
      Node := Node.GetNext;
    end;
  finally
    Nodes.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

This still traverses áll Items. Ok, just once. But if you have a really big and/or deep tree, and you want maximum efficiency, and you do not care about readability, or you just want to experiment with a TreeView's Nodes for fun, then use:

```
procedure ExpandTreeNodes(Nodes: TTreeNodes; Level: Integer);
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
  Next: TTreeNode;
begin
  if Level < 1 then
    Exit;
  Nodes.BeginUpdate;
  try
    Node := Nodes.GetFirstNode;
      while Node <> nil do
      begin
        Node.Expand(False);
        if (Node.Level < Level - 1) and Node.HasChildren then
          Node := Node.GetFirstChild
        else
        begin
          Next := Node.GetNextSibling;
          if Next <> nil then
            Node := Next
          else
            if Node.Level > 0 then
              Node := Node.Parent.GetNextSibling
            else
              Node := Node.GetNextSibling;
        end;
      end;
  finally
    Nodes.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```