# How use skin edited on VCL Skin Editor (devexpress)

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I'm having trouble using the edited skins in the devexpress editor. Any help? I do not know where to start. Should save, load, where the originals are. I am very confused.

Comment: Did you **read** and **understand** my comment from your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27359264/how-to-expand-only-to-the-second-level-of-the-treeview)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start from reading documentation. 
Refer to the "How to Create Skins Using the Skin Editor" help topic which describes SkinEditor usage. Then refer to the "How to Apply Custom Skins in the Application" help topic to learn how to use newly created skins.

You can download the documentation files from https://www.devexpress.com/ClientCenter/Downloads/Documentation/

Individual downloads for ExpressSkins™ Library  Documentation:
[CHM(3,188,493 bytes)](http://downloads.devexpress.com/Documentation/Vcl/CHM/ExpressSkinsLibraryHtmlHelpFiles.14.2.2.zip),
[PDF(5,798,057 bytes)](http://downloads.devexpress.com/Documentation/Vcl/PDF/ExpressSkinsLibraryPDFHelpFiles.14.2.2.zip),
[HLP(2,503,853 bytes)](http://downloads.devexpress.com/Documentation/Vcl/HLP/ExpressSkinsLibraryWinHelpFiles.14.2.2.zip)